# How do you fully setup an edittext into a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml, android-scrollview

Before I go into detail about the problem I have been having, I am quite new to android development so let me just explain what I would like to achieve and what I have tried to do.

I am creating an android app in eclipse IDE using the android 4.0 operating system and what I would  like to create in this app is a windowed scrollview which contains various different widgets such as check boxes, text views and edit texts. These edit texts are required so that the user can input some data about an image that is displayed in an image view on the app page but is not inside the scroll view. The user would then press a button and that data would then be stored somewhere (i know what I want to do with that) and a new image would appear, then the process repeats.

Now in order to create a windowed scrollview, I understand that you need to define the widgets inside a scrollview and to be able to scroll down to them properly is by defining them inside a linear layout and then messing around with the margin top values in each widget in the activity xml file.

However, once i created these widgets tried testing, this is where I am running into some issues.

Firstly, if a widget is placed in between the header and footer ( the region displayed on the app page and used as part of the windowed scrollview) and i try and test out the scrolling, the scrolling works but it creates a random duplicate of that widget which I cannot get rid of e.g http://community.dur.ac.uk/cs.seg05/androidapp/exhibit_A.JPG (I can't display the image to you directly as i am not a high enough rank to display an image on StackOverflow)

In an attempt to try and fix this issue, I decided that I would move everything below the footer of the scrollview and then just scroll up from there and this seemed to have worked.

Unfortunately, when trying to test out inputs into my edit texts, I ran to another annoying problems.

As soon as I finish typing into an edit text and click the next button on the soft keyboard, the app directed me to another edit text which I had not defined and displayed another soft keyboard and this in turn created a duplicate of every widget (including that edit text) that was currently displayed inside the scrollview window. (i had scrolled up in order to get to this edit text) eg 
https://community.dur.ac.uk/cs.seg05/androidapp/test.JPG

I then looked on questions such as [Scrolling EditText on ScrollView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279150/scrolling-edittext-on-scrollview-programmatically) , [How to prevent auto scrolling of EditText when keyboard appears on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181767/how-to-prevent-auto-scrolling-of-edittext-when-keyboard-appears-on-android) , [Enable Scrolling within EditText that is in a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853246/enable-scrolling-within-edittext-that-is-in-a-scrollview?rq=1)

but none of these are really helping me.

I have also tried using AutoTextCompleteView widgets as the widgets that the user woudl use as inputs but I do not fully understand how they work and I have not been able to get any data from them as when i type something into them, the program is returning that nothing has been typed.

I would really appreciate some help on this as I don't know if I am missing something, or if I have not set the widgets up correctly or if I have not set the scrollview correctly so if any of you have any solutions to these problems, please post them (code or a step by step would be very helpful).

Here is my java code in my activity (note that this a second activity that is launched once the first activity is completed).

```
 package com.example.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;




import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private String userId; //global variable as it will be used throughout this activity
    private ArrayList <String> imageNames;
    private String directory="http://community.dur.ac.uk/cs.seg05/Wild/CameraImages/";
    private int imageNumber=0;
    private CheckBox humanTest;
    private ArrayList<String> pictureIds;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras(); //obtains information passed from the previous activity
        userId= data.getString("userId"); //gets the user id from the main activity
        System.err.println("Received User  id " +userId);




        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        imageNames =getImages(userId); //gets all of the image names from the database
        System.err.println(imageNames);

         getNextImage(imageNumber, imageNames); //method that obtains the next image


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getImages(String userid) { // method that gets images from a php file
        ArrayList<String> images= new ArrayList<String>();
        pictureIds= new ArrayList<String> ();

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website= new URI("https://community.dur.ac.uk/cs.seg05/androidapp/ImageAccess.php?userid="+userid);
            HttpGet request= new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
            String l= "";
            String nl= System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((l = reader.readLine()) != null) { //converts the whole output into a string 
                sb.append(l+ nl);
        }
            reader.close();
            String result=sb.toString();






                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                System.err.println(jArray.length());
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ //retrieves the JSon
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.err.println(json_data);
                        images.add(json_data.getString("File_Name"));
                        pictureIds.add(json_data.getString("Picture_ID"));
                }  


            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }


        return images;


    }

     public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }






     public void getNextImage(int number, ArrayList<String> images) { //method that gets the images
         if (number>=images.size()) {
             String whitespace="http://www.skettymethodistchurch.org.uk/whitespace.jpg" ; //whitespace for when user has finished the subset of images
             Bitmap bm= getBitmapFromURL(whitespace);
                ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //gets the image view
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
         }
         else {
             String image=images.get(number);
             String request=directory+image;
             Bitmap bm= getBitmapFromURL(request);
             ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //gets the image view
            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
            imageNumber++;

         }
     }

     public void loadNextImage(View view) { //method for when the next button is clicked
         try {
        // humanTest = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);




             ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //gets the image view

             iv.setImageBitmap(null);
             getNextImage(imageNumber, imageNames);
         }



         catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e);
         }
}



     public void LoadHelpActivity(View view) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HelpActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
     }

     public void getScore(View view) {
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
     }

}
```

Here is the xml file associated with this activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hello.SecondActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >  


             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                 android:layout_width="315dp"
                 android:layout_height="150dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

 <!-- Header aligned to top --> 
  <RelativeLayout
                 android:id="@+id/header"
                 android:layout_width="315dp"
                 android:layout_height="35dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:gravity="center" >

                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="355dp"
                     android:layout_height="25dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                     android:text="Scroll up to classify the contents of the image"
                     android:textColor="#000"
                     android:textSize="14sp" />
             </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
     />
  </RelativeLayout>


  <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollableContents" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_above="@id/footer"
     android:layout_below="@id/header"
      android:isScrollContainer="false"
      android:fillViewport="true"
     >


    <LinearLayout

      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="vertical" >



             <CheckBox
                 android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                 android:layout_width="150dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                 android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

                 android:text="Humans in image" />




            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="13"




        />





              <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
                 android:layout_width="95dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"           
                 android:onClick="loadNextImage"
                 android:text="@string/classify" />



</LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:onClick="LoadHelpActivity"
      android:text="Help" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
      android:onClick="getScore"
      android:text="Check score" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, here is the android manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"
            android:label="Wild Eyes" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.SecondActivity"
            android:label="Wild Eyes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.HelpActivity"
            android:label="Wild Eyes" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If there is anything that I have missed and that would be beneficial, do let me know and I will post it.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I would really appreciate some help on this as I don't fully get it

Comment: its really hard to understand what it is that you try to accomplish (especially since the images are gone) but if i understand the problem  - you need to auto scroll to different widgets inside the scroll view on a push of a button -  then i did something similar once - i had text views that it needed to scroll to using key press, which if i understand is what you need try this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312940/how-to-set-different-actions-to-dynamiclly-created-button-on-android-specifical/20360971#20360971 now change the keystroke on the keyboard to the action i used

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. Apologies that the image disappeared, that particular image has been removed from that url , hence why you can't view it anymore

Comment: did it help you or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: It did help. I did also find that I was only having this problem on the emulator and not on the actual phone I was developing it for